Getting error "Oops something went wrong" after reloading gnome with Alt+f2 and "r"
I have Ubuntu 24.04 with Gnome-shell 46. So whenever I am trying to restart gnome-shell with Alt+F2 and r, it is showing "oops something went wrong" and had to Logout to fix the issue. It happens whenever I do this while another application is already open.
This is same bug as this one This.
The issue I provided has some patches which worked for Gnome 45 and Mutter 42. But in my Ubuntu and gnome version it doesn't work and it already has patched code.
I tried to see in log and here is my out of 
journalctl  /usr/bin/gnome-shell \

Aug 04 02:49:23 rudrasama gnome-shell[3225]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Aug 04 02:49:24 rudrasama gnome-shell[3225]: Window manager warning: Property WM_NAME on window 0x3200046 contained invalid UTF-8
Aug 04 02:49:25 rudrasama gnome-shell[3225]: Window manager error: Another compositing manager is already running on screen 0 on display “:1”.
Aug 04 02:49:25 rudrasama gnome-shell[15645]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Aug 04 02:49:25 rudrasama gnome-shell[15645]: Window manager warning: Property WM_NAME on window 0x3200046 contained invalid UTF-8
Aug 04 02:49:26 rudrasama gnome-shell[15645]: Window manager error: Another compositing manager is already running on screen 0 on display “:1”.
Aug 04 02:49:26 rudrasama gnome-shell[15697]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Aug 04 02:49:27 rudrasama gnome-shell[15697]: Window manager warning: Property WM_NAME on window 0x3200046 contained invalid UTF-8
Aug 04 02:49:28 rudrasama gnome-shell[15697]: Window manager error: Another compositing manager is already running on screen 0 on display “:1”.
Aug 04 02:49:28 rudrasama gnome-shell[15753]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Aug 04 02:49:28 rudrasama gnome-shell[15753]: Window manager warning: Property WM_NAME on window 0x3200046 contained invalid UTF-8
Aug 04 02:49:29 rudrasama gnome-shell[15753]: Window manager error: Another compositing manager is already running on screen 0 on display “:1”.
Aug 04 02:49:33 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Will monitor session c2
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Extension ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com will not be loaded
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Extension ding@rastersoft.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com will not be loaded
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Extension ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com will not be loaded
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Extension tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com already installed in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com. /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com will not be loaded
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama org.gnome.Shell.desktop[16157]: Window manager warning: Failed to parse saved session file: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3/.config/mutter/sessions/10da452662bce180dd172271997385079200000161320000.ms”: No such file or directory
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Aug 04 02:49:35 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: no authentication service is enabled, using password authentication
Aug 04 02:49:36 rudrasama gnome-shell[16157]: Registering session with GDM
Aug 04 02:49:44 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 46.2) as a X11 window and compositing manager
Aug 04 02:49:45 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Unset XDG_SESSION_ID, getCurrentSessionProxy() called outside a user session. Asking logind directly.
Aug 04 02:49:45 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Will monitor session 18
Aug 04 02:49:45 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Gio.UnixInputStream has been moved to a separate platform-specific library. Please update your code to use GioUnix.InputStream instead.
                                              0 inhibit() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/loginManager.js":209:8]
                                              1 InterpretGeneratorResume() ["self-hosted":1461:33]
                                              2 AsyncFunctionNext() ["self-hosted":852:26]
                                              3 anonymous() ["resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/init.js":21:19]
Aug 04 02:49:45 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug 04 02:49:46 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: GFileInfo created without standard::icon
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: file ../../../gio/gfileinfo.c: line 1765 (g_file_info_get_icon): should not be reached
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor panelBox [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor panel [Gjs_ui_panel_Panel] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor panelRight [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [StBin] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [Gjs_ubuntu-appindicators_ubuntu_com_indicatorStatusIcon_IndicatorTrayIcon] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [StBoxLayout] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [ShellTrayIcon] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [MetaWindowGroup] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [MetaWindowActorX11] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Can't update stage views actor unnamed [MetaSurfaceActorX11] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: GNOME Shell started at Sun Aug 04 2024 02:49:45 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Registering session with GDM
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama org.gnome.Shell.desktop[16157]: XIO:  fatal IO error 4 (Interrupted system call) on X server ":0"
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama org.gnome.Shell.desktop[16157]:       after 2568 requests (2568 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Launching DING process
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: (gjs:17600): Gjs-WARNING **: 02:49:47.887: GLib.unix_signal_add has been moved to a separate platform-specific library. Please update your code to use GLibUnix.signal_add instead.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: 0 DesktopManager() ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/desktopManager.js":263:12]
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: 1 anonymous() ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/ding.js":180:25]
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: 2 anonymous() ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/ding.js":197:20]
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: 3 <TOP LEVEL> ["/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ding@rastersoft.com/app/ding.js":206:12]
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: DBus interface for Switcheroo control (net.hadess.SwitcherooControl) is now available.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: DBus interface for Nautilus (org.gnome.Nautilus.FileOperations2) is now available.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: DBus interface for Nautilus (org.freedesktop.FileManager1) is now available.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: DBus interface for Gvfs daemon (org.gtk.vfs.Metadata) is now available.
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: ** Message: 02:49:47.962: Connecting to org.freedesktop.Tracker3.Miner.Files
Aug 04 02:49:47 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: GNOME nautilus 46.2
Aug 04 02:49:48 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: DING: DBus interface for File-roller (org.gnome.ArchiveManager1) is now available.
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Aug 04 02:49:49 rudrasama gnome-shell[16856]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).

As you can see, it has the same error as the issue link I mentioned:

Window manager error: Another compositing manager is already running on screen 0 on display ":1"


I too had this problem in GNOME 46 but I think upto 46.4 version. When any one window is open while restarting the shell, it effects. But I think from 46.5 or 46.6 this issue is gone.

@PRATAP there is no Gnome 46.6 for Ubuntu 24.04. It doesn't come with official release and we can't even upgrade it to 46.6. It is stuck on 46.0.

Yes Ubuntu updates takes time after GNOME releases newer version. I use only gnome-shell with arch linux but I occasionally tests gnome-shell with Ubuntu 24.04.

@PRATAP aah okay, I guess I should jump to Arch Linux now. Anyway Thank you for your reply!.

Only workaround I used was to make sure all windows are closed before hitting Alt+F2 and r

@PRATAP well yeah in Ubuntu if you close your all windows and hit Alt+F2 and r then it works without throwing error.

Nice to hear that @RudraSama
